# Related entities in EF are missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

how i can multiple my tables information in one view, i want show my player club not his club_id : [image]

Im sitting and dont understand how to do this last days, i want see result like this :
[image]

Here is my 2 tables picture:
[image]

My ActionResult Index1():
[image]

When i run this, c# throw error 
[image]

I understand that error is in this row
  ClubName = x.BasketballClub.ClubName
but i dont have any variants what i need to do ......
without clubname its works great 
[image]

Comment: your viewmodel and your control are OK, you need to change the view so it does not display the information you do not want to display and add the ones you'd like to see

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Q3jkp

Comment: here is my view , for Index Action , whats here is wrong?

Comment: sorry, i see now, `BasketballClub` is null, so it throws an exception, Amal Sebastian gave you an answer

Comment: i try Amal Sebastion Solution, but it doesnt work!

Comment: Ok, insert your `Player` class and your configuration of the entity framework if you are using [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: and please post code, not image of your code, use Code tags to format it ( {} button )

Comment: im not using Fluent Api i dont know what is it

Comment: @GintarsLazda MVC doesn't deal with tables and data access, it's a web application framework. That's the job of ORMs like Entity Framework. In any case, post your *code*, not pictures. Post your *Entity Framework* configuration and your entity classes. Do they have the proper attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PlayerIndex1Model
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Why this ???
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; } 

    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public int PlayerWeight { get; set; }
    public string PlayerSurname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string PlayerPosition { get; set; }
    public decimal PlayerHeight { get; set; }

    public string ClubName { get; set; }



    [ForeignKey("BasketBallClub")]
    public int BasketBallClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual BasketBallClub BasketBallClub
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class BasketBallClub
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; } 
}


public ActionResult Index1()
{
    List<Player> playerList =  new List<Player>();

    BasketDbContext db = new BasketDbContext();
    List<Player> playerList = db.Player.ToList(); 

    /* if not load BasketballClub try this way
    var playerList = new List<Player>();
    using (var db = new BasketDbContext())
    {
        playerList = db.Player.Include(x=>x.BasketballClub).ToList();  
    }
    */

    PlayerIndex1Model playerVM = new PlayerIndex1Model();

    List<PlayerIndex1Model> playerVMList = playerList.Select(x => new PlayerIndex1Model
    {
        PlayerName = x.PlayerName,
        Id = x.Id,
        PlayerHeight=x.PlayerHeight,
        PlayerSurname=x.PlayerSurname,
        PlayerPosition=x.PlayerPosition,
        Birthday=x.Birthday,

        PlayerWeight=x.PlayerWeight,
        BasketBallClubId = x.BasketballClubId,
        ClubName = x.BasketBallClub?.ClubName ?? "" //if BasketballClub is not null returns ClubName otherwise ""

    }).ToList();

    return View(playerVMList);
}
```

**Fluent Api Example.** [Tutorial Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx)

```
public class BasketDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BasketDbContext()
        : base("BasketDb")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Player> Player { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BasketBallClub> BasketBallClub { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PlayerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BasketBallClubMap());
    }

}

using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
public class PessoaMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
{
    public PlayerMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.PlayerName).HasMaxLength(50); //.HasColumnName("player_name");
        Property(t => t.PlayerSurname).HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(t => t.PlayerWeight);
        //..... configure all columns 

        //Relationships

        HasRequired(t => t.BasketBallClub)
                .WithMany(t => t.Players)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BasketBallClubId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
public class BasketBallClubMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BasketBallClub>
{
    public BasketBallClubMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Id); //.HasColumnName("id");
        Property(t => t.ClubName).HasMaxLength(50); //.HasColumnName("club_name");
    }
}

// Your Model
public class PlayerIndex1Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string PlayerSurname { get; set; }
    //... omitted other columns 
    public int BasketBallClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual BasketBallClub BasketBallClub { get; set; }
}

public class BasketBallClub
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }

    public virtual IColletion<Player> Players { get;set; } 
}
```

Comment: Maaan you save my life

Comment: this works great  /* if not load BasketballClub try this way
    var playerList = new List<Player>();
    using (var db = new BasketDbContext())
    {
        playerList = db.Player.Include(x=>x.BasketballClub).ToList();  
    }
    */

Comment: @GintarsLazda very good, I've edited the answer and it includes an example of how to use Fluent Api, things get clearer in my opinion, if the answer was enough to solve your problem mark it as the right answer, this helps anyone who has the same problem finding the solution

Answer (score 1):

Set BasketBallClubId As ForeignKey in  playerIndexModel which will refer to 
   BasketBallClub Model

```
  [ForeignKey("BasketBallClub ")]
    public int BasketBallClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual BasketBallClub BasketBallClub { get; set;
```

Now you can Access BasketBall Please See with The names of models  since you haven't included the models here  , hope you get an idea how to do

Answer (score 0):

here is My code
Index1 ActionResult

```html
 public class PlayerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index1()
        {
            BasketDbContext db = new BasketDbContext();
            List<Player> playerList = db.Player.ToList();

            PlayerIndex1Model playerVM = new PlayerIndex1Model();

            List<PlayerIndex1Model> playerVMList = playerList.Select(x => new PlayerIndex1Model
            {

                PlayerName = x.PlayerName,
                Id = x.Id,
                PlayerHeight=x.PlayerHeight,
                PlayerSurname=x.PlayerSurname,
                PlayerPosition=x.PlayerPosition,
                Birthday=x.Birthday,
                
                PlayerWeight=x.PlayerWeight,
                BasketBallClubId = x.BasketballClubId,
                ClubName = x.BasketballClub.ClubName
                                  
            }).ToList();

            return View(playerVMList);
        }
```

PlayerIndex1Model.cs

```html
using Basket.Data.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Basket.Web.Models
{
    public class PlayerIndex1Model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public int PlayerWeight { get; set; }
        public string PlayerSurname { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string PlayerPosition { get; set; }
        public decimal PlayerHeight { get; set; }

        public string ClubName { get; set; }

        //fk

        [ForeignKey("BasketBallClub")]
        public int BasketBallClubId { get; set; }
        public virtual BasketBallClub BasketBallClub
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
}
```

And cshtml

```html
@model IEnumerable<Basket.Web.Models.PlayerIndex1Model>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index1";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Index1</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerWeight)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerSurname)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birthday)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerPosition)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlayerHeight)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClubName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BasketBallClubId)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerWeight)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerSurname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birthday)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerPosition)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerHeight)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClubName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BasketBallClubId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Comment: If you want to add more info, update your question. Answers are for answers. *Don't* dump the entire project though. Your question has nothing to do with MVC anyway, it's 100% entity framework. You could write a test that creates a context, executes the query you want and displays the same error. Post *that*, not the view

Comment: BTW `List<Player> playerList = db.Player.ToList();` loads **all** players in memory. Don't do that. Create a LINQ query that returns what you want and call `.ToList()` on that, eg `db.Player.Select(x=>x => new PlayerIndex1Model {...)).ToList(). This may even solve the problem as EF will load all related entities at once